# Excel VBA: reference table header# in concatenate function

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add a column (7) to a table and filling the cells in that column with a CONCATENATE of column (6) and (5)

I can make it work by using the header name but would like to use the column number instead. Any suggestions on how to make this work?

This is what I have:

```
Sub AddColAndName(ws As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject, newColPos As Long, newColName As String, conColPos1 As Long, conColPos2 As Long)

    With tbl
        .ListColumns.Add newColPos
        .HeaderRowRange(newColPos) = newColName
        .ListColumns(newColPos).DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE([@FinancialMonthNumberNameShort],[@FinancialYear])"
    End With

    With ws
        .Columns(newColPos).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub
```

I would like to change the [@FinancialMonthNameShort] to the number passed as argument (conColPos1).. or any other way where I can use an argument passed to the Sub.

Thanks you all for helping.

//JATE

Comment: If you want to use the column number, maybe something like `Range("MyTable[[#Headers],[FinancialMonthNumberNameShort]]").Column` can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet17") 'change as required
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table5") 'change as required

    Dim newColPos As Long
    Dim conColPos1 As Long
    Dim conColPos2 As Long

    If conColPos1  > tbl.Range.Columns.Count  Or conColPos2 > tbl.Range.Columns.Count Then
        MsgBox "Invalid columns for concatenation"
        End
    End If

    conColPos1 = 2
    conColPos2 = 3
    newColPos = 4

    Dim newColName As String
    newColName = "NewColumn"

    AddColAndName ws, tbl, newColPos, newColName, conColPos1, conColPos2

End Sub

Public Sub AddColAndName(ByVal ws As Worksheet,ByVal tbl As ListObject, ByVal newColPos As Long,ByVal newColName As String,ByVal conColPos1 As Long, ByVal conColPos2 As Long)

    With tbl

        If newColPos > .Range.Columns.Count Then
            .ListColumns.Add .Range.Columns.Count + 1
        Else
            .Add newColPos
        End If

        .HeaderRowRange(newColPos) = newColName
        .ListColumns(newColPos).DataBodyRange.Formula = "=CONCATENATE([@" & .HeaderRowRange(conColPos1) & "],[@" & .HeaderRowRange(conColPos2) & "])"

    End With
    With ws
        .Columns(newColPos).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub
```

You could also swop out and use:

```
.ListColumns(newColPos).DataBodyRange.Formula = "=CONCATENATE([@" & .ListColumns(conColPos1).Cells(1, 1) & "],[@" & .ListColumns(conColPos2).Cells(1, 1) & "])"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The solution worked perfectly. I love that you are checking if columns used for concatenation are valid.

(The line you suggest I could swap out threw an error but the "real" solution you posted is perfect. Thanks.)

Comment: The "If conColPos1 Or conColPos2 > tbl.Range.Columns.Count Then" runs the Then part as long as conColPos1 is not 0... why is that? (I moved the part setting the variables to above the "If" statement)

Comment: It was to stop an attempt to concatenate columns that don't exist within the table.

Comment: Yes, I really like that it is there, I just don't understand why it does not work as expected. If conColPos1 = 6 and conColPos2 = 5 and tbl.Range.Columns.Count returns 6... why does the if conColPos1 Or conColPos2 > tbl.Range.Columns.Count  run the Then part? - only when conColPos1 = 0 it passes the Then part of the code...

Comment: If I split the check into 2 separate statements (so I don't use the "Or") then it works flawlessly. Thanks again QHarr

Comment: Because I was thinking in the wrong language. Have updated.

Comment: Now I get it - Thank you so much

Comment: You should probably add a check that  conColPos1 <> newColPos And conColPos2<> newColPos to avoid circular reference.